# ATG - One to Many mapping and list property results

Tags: sql, oracle, join, repository, atg

I am trying to do some I supposed to be very simple ... but I have some problems.

TABLE PROVINCE:

```
CODISTPROV  NAME     SIGPROV
1           MILAN    MI
2           ROME     RM
3           NAPLES   NA
```

and TABLE COMUNI:

```
CODISTPROV CODISTCOM DESC_COM
1          1         XX1
1          2         XX2
2          3         YY3
2          4         YY4
3          5         ZZ5
```

where CODISTPROV in COMUNI is FOREIGN KEY TO PROVINCE.

The xml is

```
<item-descriptor name="comuniWithSiglaProvincia" writable="false" item-cache-timeout="86400000" item-expire-timeout="604800000">
   <table name="province" type="primary" id-column-names="codistprov">
        <property name="sigla_provincia" data-type="String" column-name="sigprov" display-name-resource="Sigla provincia"/>      
   </table>
   <table name="comuni" type="multi" id-column-names="codistprov,codistcom" multi-column-name="codistcom">      
            <property name="listaComuni" data-type="list" component-data-type="String" column-name="desc_com" />            
   </table>
</item-descriptor>
```

I'd like to implement this query

```
SELECT C.DESC_COM,P.SIGPROV 
FROM COMUNI C, PROVINCE P 
WHERE C.DESC_COM LIKE 'PAR%' AND C.CODISTPROV = P.CODISTPROV;
```

where PAR are some characters from input.
The code:

```
RepositoryView view = getTopoAnagraficaRepository().getView("comuniWithSiglaProvincia");
Object params[] = new Object[1];
params[0] = comuneInitialCharacters;

QueryBuilder repositoryBuilder = view.getQueryBuilder();
QueryExpression prop = repositoryBuilder.createPropertyQueryExpression(PROPERTY_LISTA_COMUNI);
QueryExpression value = repositoryBuilder.createConstantQueryExpression(new String(comuneInitialCharacters));                                           
Query query = repositoryBuilder.createPatternMatchQuery(prop, value, QueryBuilder.STARTS_WITH);

listRepItem = view.executeQuery(query); // 19 results
if(listRepItem != null){
for (RepositoryItem item : listRepItem) {
        System.out.println("PROV=" + item.getPropertyValue("sigla_provincia")); // it prints correct value
    if (item.getPropertyValue("listaComuni") != null)  // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException
     [...]
```

The query return 19 listRepItem (it is correct) but I got ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException in the last line above, when I try to access the sublist.

Any hints?
What is the correct way to access a property value which is a list?

For example with the data above, if input characters were 'XX' I should have as results

```
XX1 MI
XX2 MI
```

Thanks

Comment: Please confirm if you are getting any errors in the log relating to repositories prior to the "Nucleus running ..." message?

Comment: Yes, I confirm it

Comment: Please include the error you are seeing in your question?

Answer (score 1):

So what I believe you are trying to achieve is represent the below data model in a `Repository` as follows:

```
|
|-- Country1  
|   |
|   |------- Province1
|   |------- Province2
|   |------- Province3
|-- Country2
    |
    |------- Province4
    |------- Province5
    |------- Province6
```

To achieve this in the repository definition you should probably use a `set` instead of a `list`.  The documentation states:

> The multi-column-name attribute ensures that the ordering of the multi-values are maintained. The column specified by the multi-column-name attribute is used for multi-valued properties of data type array, map, and list and is not used for sets (which are unordered). For map type properties, the values in the column specifiedy by the multi-column-name attribute must be a string. *For list or array type properties, these values should be an integer or numeric type, and must be sequential.*

To achieve this your repository definition for Country would look something like this:

```
<item-descriptor display-name-resource="Country"  use-id-for-path="false" content="false" writable="true" default="true" display-property="name" folder="false" cache-mode="simple" id-separator=":" name="country" >
    <table shared-table-sequence="1" name="COUNTRY" id-column-name="id" type="primary">
        <property readable="true" queryable="true"  hidden="false" backing-map-property="false" name="id" column-name="ID" data-type="string" required="true" writable="true"/>
        <property readable="true" queryable="true" display-name="Name" cache-mode="inherit" backing-map-property="false" name="name" column-name="DISPLAY_NAME" data-type="string" required="true" writable="true"/>
    </table>
    <table shared-table-sequence="1" name="COUNTRY_PROVINCE" id-column-names="COUNTRY_ID" type="multi">
        <property readable="true" display-name-resource="provinces" data-type="set" component-item-type="province" required="false" writable="true" queryable="true" cache-mode="inherit" backing-map-property="false" name="provinces" column-name="PROVINCE_ID"/>
    </table>
</item-descriptor>
```

The province repository definition would look something like this:

```
<item-descriptor display-name-resource="Province" default="false" expert="false" display-property="name" folder="false"  id-separator=":" name="province" use-id-for-path="false" content="false" writable="true">
    <table shared-table-sequence="1" name="Province" id-column-name="id" type="primary">
        <property readable="true" queryable="true" expert="false" hidden="false" cache-mode="inherit" backing-map-property="false" name="id" column-name="ID" data-type="string" required="true" writable="true"/>
        <property readable="true" queryable="true" expert="false" hidden="false" display-name="Name" cache-mode="inherit" backing-map-property="false" name="name" column-name="DISPLAY_NAME" data-type="string" required="true" writable="true"/>
    </table>
</item-descriptor>
```

More information can be found in the [Oracle Commerce Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E69533_01/Platform.11-3/ATGRepositoryGuide/html/s0606onetomanyrelationshipsmultivalue01.html).

Comment: I still got the same exception also with set, on the statement:
item.getPropertyValue("provinces")
What is the correct way to iterate on the results?

Comment: I tried something like: java.util.Set<RepositoryItem> set = (java.util.Set<RepositoryItem>) item.getPropertyValue("provinces");

Comment: See this note also https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E69533_01/Platform.11-3/ATGRepositoryGuide/html/s0607operatingonmultivaluedproperties01.html

Comment: In your example I don't understand why you used 3 tables: COUNTRY, COUNTRY_PROVINCE and province. I think COUNTRY_PROVINCE is not necessary